# What are the Stargate dial home device symbols used to dial Earth from Atlantis?

Tags: stargate, stargate-atlantis

Could someone please show me the dial home device symbols used to dial Earth from Atlantis?

It's for my son, who will be carving them into stone.

Answer (score 24):

The show's producer was kind enough to share them [on his website](https://josephmallozzi.com/2013/03/26/march-26-2013-you-asked-for-it-atlantis-floor-plans-the-control-room-the-zpm-room-weirs-office-the-adrift-lifeline-art-department-package/)

[image]

[image]

Comment: You'd think that such a super-advanced race would have a better writing system...

Comment: @RonJohn - I could improve English in a heartbeat if I was dictator of the world. Do we really need the letter K when a double C will do just fine?

Comment: @RonJohn I think that these are visual representations of constellations, not a writing system.  The stargates in the milky way had a runic-style writing system.

Comment: @Valorum: We do, because C should be used exclusively for the "ch" sound, with S and K being used for the other uses of C. :-)

Comment: @RBarryYoung The Milky Way stargates also used constellations, with the exception of the point-of-origin symbol for Earth.

Comment: @Valorum we're not a super-advanced race, though, are we?

Comment: @RBarryYoung but constellations are only "real" from on planet's perspective.

Comment: @RonJohn Not if the observer is *really* far away from the items making up the constellation. Constellations comprised entirely of other galaxies would probably all be roughly identical anywhere within a particular galaxy.

Comment: @ZakA.Klajda except constellations are made up of bright stars, which means close stars. Polaris, for example, is only 300-400 light years away.

Comment: @called2voyage I've a running theory that the Earth point-of-origin was actually a constellation we're roughly inside of (or at least, isn't visible from Earth):  It doesn't exist _only_ on the Earth stargate.  Plus don't forget Earth actually has two.